# Ubuntu18.04: Logging in loop after mounting sdb5 on /home

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, gparted, fstab

Ubuntu18.04:

I found the space of / directory is not enough.So I tried mounting sdb(formatted through GParted) on /home.

Process:

1. After formatting a new part sdb4(10G) and sdb5(1.8T) on disk sdb using GParted, I found there was a "!" on /boot/efi part(mounted on sdb1)
2. `mv -rf /home /backup`
3. got uuid of /dev/sdb5 by `blkid` and edit /etc/fstab
4. `sudo mount -a`
5. I found the sdb5 really mounted on /home by `df -h`
6. `mv -rf /backup/username /home`
7. `reboot` (an error occurs on screen "failed deactivating swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxx",but i have commented the swap in /etc/fstab)
8. come to the log-in interface: after entering password, it come back to the log-in...

So how could I solve this, please?

Comment: You haven't mentioned your OS & release details, but a GUI login requires work files to be created in your $HOME, so if that wasn't setup on your newly formatted disk (ie. directory structure setup with user directories), a GUI login will fall & you'll return to greeter/DM (same issue as if there is no available disk space).  However a text login will work allowing you to explore & correct your issue.  What OS & release are you using?

Comment: ubuntu18.04.4 lts

Comment: @guiverc What do you mean by " directory structure setup", please?

Comment: My $USER is "guiverc", so I need to have a `/home/guiverc/` which I own for a GUI to create files there.  If you've mounted your /dev/sdb5 to /home/, I'd have to ensure there exists a `/guiverc/` in the root directory (the /home/ isn't needed as handled in my example, by the way I'd mount it in my *file system table* or `/etc/fstab` entry.

Comment: There actually exists a /username in /home. After I change the owner of /username, it works. Thank you anyway.@guiverc

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we should ensure that /home/username has a **non-root owner**...

1. ll /home/username
2. if "root" exists in the 3rd or 4st column, run:
   sudo chown username:username /home/username -R

It works for me.